Uniform convergence of series of holomorphic functions on compact sets follows from absolute convergence
Suppose $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n$ is a series summing functions $f_n$ holomorphic on an open domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ and it converges absolutely on $\Omega$.
If $K \subset \mathbb \Omega$ is compact, does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n$ converge uniformly on $K$?

how is absolute convergence of a sequence of functions defined?

Thanks, fixed it.

It would be helpful if you explicitly state what it means for a sequence of holomorphic functions to converge absolutely on $\Omega$.

not necessarily - the usual concept that works is normal convergence which means that $|f_n(z)| \le K(n), z \in K$ and $\sum_n K(n) < \infty$ for every compact $K$; pointwise absolute convergence doesn't imply uniform convergence on compacts
